# Customize font size

Tags: fontsize, boxes, scalerel

What is the best way of using (large) custom font sizes in latex documents (e.g., for title pages)?

I thought of using `\scalebox`. I have also seen there exists a `\newfont` command - can this be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For type 1 fonts (which is generally the case) you can simply use, if you want, say a 48pt size for your title:

```
{\fontsize{48}{60}\selectfont My Big Title}
```